# Double clicked aspx page goes to Mozilla instead of desinger

Tags: visual-studio

Need help!

I don't know what I did but every time I double-click an aspx page in visual studio, it goes to Mozilla.

[image]
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your file association for 'aspx' files is Visual Studio.

Right-click on an 'aspx' file, click 'Open with...", select Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just open .aspx files (or .php files, or any similar ones) in a browser and expect to see the website rendered. You need a webserver to do that.

Normally, that webserver for .aspx pages on Windows would be IIS. But if you're just developing the site on your machine, the developer webserver that's part of Visual Studio should suffice. If you open the solution in Visual Studio, you do that by pressing Ctrl+F5 (by default).